# How to sync a multiprocessing.Event list from parent to child process in real-time?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, replay

I have a requirement to retrieve and replay a trace file (in python) containing transactions from different processes. We have to simulate the original scenrios in trace file, so we first separate the trace file into different pieces in each of which only contains the transactions from the single process and replay them in parallel. And further, in order to maintain the same ordering of different processes' transactions reflected in original trace, a series of multiprocessing.Event primitives are inserted in specific points of each piece for interprocess synchronization.

Our program mainly handle 2 steps **asynchronously**, retrieving and replaying. And since the trace file is very big, we would process it chunk-by-chunk:

1. **The main (parent) process** retrieves the the trace file chunk by chunk. For each chunk, different pieces would be generated and the multiprocessing.Event primitives are inserted for interprocess synchronization in later replay. The main process maintains a Event() list, whenever a processes-intertwined point is detected, the list incremented via eventList.append(Event()), and this new appended Event() would be referenced by eventList[i].set and eventList[i].wait pair which are inserted to specific points in 2 pieces. As soon as the first chunk is processed, child processes are spawned and the pieces would be distributed to respective child process for replaying. Later retrieved chunks would be thrown to the queue for respective childs.
2. **Child processes** are spawned after first chunk is retrieved by parent. Each child process replays one single piece which contains the transactions from same process.

The problem here is that the child processes are spawned just after the first chunk retrieved, so the eventList at this time point would be copy to child processes and it's ok for synchronized replaying the first chunk, but the main process now continues processing the second chunk, and **the eventList incremented for the second chunk would not be realized by the child processes, and when later replaying the second chunk, the program fails**.

I realize that the multiprocessing.Manager supporting list can share the memory between different processes, but seems the list can not accommodate Event(). The exception "RuntimeError: Semaphore objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance" pops up when append a Event() to Manager().list().  I tried also auto-generate new variable eventXX=Manager().Event() whenever needed, but seems it causes the performance dramatically decreased.

Does somebody know how can I make the child process realizes such multiprocessing.Event list change in parent? Or do you have any other methods for achieving this?

Thanks in advance.